# 端末上の emacs が 256 色を表示してくれない

Tags: emacs, ubuntu, putty, 端末エミュレーター

PuTTY で、 ubuntu に接続し、その上で emacs を起動しています。
以下の条件を満たしているのですが、 emacs が 256 色を表示してくれません。
何が原因でしょうか。

## 症状

emacs が 8色しか表示してくれない。具体的には、 load-theme の結果が８色しか存在しないし、

```
(list-colors-display)
```

を実行しても８色しか表示されない。

## 環境

- emacs プロセスが認識している TERM 環境変数: xterm-256color
- `tput colors` も `256`
- PuTTY の色の設定:

  - Allow terminal to use xterm 256-colour mode にチェック
  - その他詳細は添付画像に表示
- ubuntu から 256 色出力自体は、可能である模様

  - 添付ファイル2つめ参照
- tmux などはマルチプレクサは使っていない

## 各種ソフトウェアのバージョン

- ubuntu: 14.04
- emacs: 25.1 (手元でビルド)
- PuTTY: 0.66

## 添付画像

PuTTY 色の設定
[image: PuTTY 色の設定]

256色出力
[image: 256色出力]

Comment: @argus tmux が悪さをしている可能性を考え、 tmux を利用していない状態で試したのですが、上記の通りの状態で、割と途方に暮れています。。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

global-company-mode を after-init-hook に追加していたのですが、このパッケージが存在していないために、 after-init の処理が途中で異常終了していることが原因でした。

company-mode をインストールすると正しく動作しました。